# Hazelcast IQueue in clusterd environment receives item on all the members

Tags: hazelcast

I am using client server topology in myproject and trying to execute some operations on my hazelcast server.

I am putting the serialized bean on my hazelcast queue from client as below

```
IQueue<SerializedBean> queue = HzUtil.getInstance().getQueue("myqueue");

boolean  status = queue.offer(serializedBean,<timeoutvalue>,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS );
```

on my hazelcast server I have registered listener and I am running hazelcast in cluster mode.

```
<hz:queue name="myqueue">
    <hz:item-listeners>
        <hz:item-listener implementation="myqueueImpl" include-value="true"/>
    </hz:item-listeners>
</hz:queue>


    public class MyqueueImpl implements ItemListener<SerializedBean> {

        public void itemAdded(ItemEvent<SerializedBean> inputMessage) {
            System.out.println("Item added to the queue ");
            //sometask
        }

    public void itemRemoved(ItemEvent<SerializedBean> removedItem) {

            System.out.println("Item removed from the queue ");
        }
}
```

Issue:

what I have observed that the queue item is received and picked up and executed on both the members of the cluster. I want the item to be picked up only once  once on any of the cluster member. Please let me know what exactly I am missing

Comment: Please suggest if anyone can throw some light on this ?

Answer (score 0):

The ItemListener works exactly like other listeners in Hazelcast (except the local EntryListener on IMap). You're looking for a solution like poll, as far as I understand and that cannot be achieved using a ItemListener. Please see the docs on how to retrieve the value on one node only: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.7/manual/html-single/index.html#getting-a-queue-and-putting-items